# How can I avoid the irrelevant number of sentences in the result?

Tags: nlp, bert, semantic-similarity

The nature of the data I have is not arranged; however, I'm trying to extract the appropriate sentences for each query as a sample for ground truth. Also, the most critical problem is that I use the BERT model, which searches for the top 500 sentences in which the similarity value is greater than the 0.5 threshold. So the result is disorganized. For example, I got for a query

```
5 for the relevant, 495 for the irrelevant, and 6 for the Total relevant
```

How can I avoid the irrelevant number of sentences in the result?

Comment: It seems you have labeled data about the relevant/irrelevant sentences, so you may train a classifier to discard the irrelevant ones.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The sentences themselves are not labeled, but it will take time for me to label them manually. Can I share the code here to ensure that I'm on the right way?

Comment: How did you know that 495 sentences were irrelevant?

Comment: I wrote in the code
`top_k = min(500, len(content_list))` so the results will be the first top 500 sentences, then I revised them to capture the right sentences for the query I asked

Comment: I see. I am afraid that if you can't produce relevant/irrelevant labels easily, I don't see how you can remove the irrelevant ones automatically. Maybe using ChatGPT to create a dataset based on some hand-made examples.

Comment: How can I ask it, please?  Do you mean I provide it with the database and ask it to create  the labels?

Comment: Can I change the top_k with the total of relevant sentences so I can minimize the irrelevant ones? as every query has a different  total of relevant

Comment: About the `top_k`, you should check if the most relevant are distributed at the top or not. About ChatGPT, I would do it programmatically with the API, one by one; I'm not sure how I'd go about it with the web interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and time. I will try to use ChatGPT, but the last two questions, please. Will making top_k a constant for each query be a good attempt or not? and the other question , can i compare using BERT with TF-IDF or is it not a good attempt

Comment: I already replied to the `top_k` issue in my previous comment. About TF-IDF, no idea, sorry.